# Continue running code in background ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, multithreading, scheduling

I need to run the code every 15 seconds in background which is not effect on server.

I have below a sample table for auction data.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
AID           STARTDATE               ENDDATE
-------------------------------------------------------------
1             18-7-2013 12:00 PM     20-7-2013 12:00 PM
2             19-7-2013 12:00 PM     21-7-2013 12:00 PM
3             19-7-2013 01:00 PM     21-7-2013 12:00 PM
4             19-7-2013 01:00 PM     22-7-2013 12:00 PM
```

i need to check in table for get the item which is present date is greater than start date,
then i will get the data through the web request that auction store in local db, it will be loop for every 15 secs until the present date is greater than enddate.
Some time 2 auction start at same time then i need to run two thread simultaneously.

What is the best way to get an update every 15 seconds for all items which are currently in running auction mode and store in our database?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that reliably in ASP.NET/IIS.  The whole process by default doesn't start until the first request from the web server is received, then the whole process shuts down after the specified inactivity time (usually 20 minutes).  If you need a process to run every 15 seconds, you have to initial a request from the client side every 15 seconds, most likely using some sort of javascript to do the request.

Best solution is to update your your auction database with a windows service, separate from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you hosting your website? If you are on your own server, create a cron job that makes a request to your backend every 15 seconds.

If you are using cloud providers (or providers without the "cloud" catchphrase), they might offer cron job functionality. But they rarely let you implement 15-second intervals, which, if it comes from a different site, some providers might interpret as DOS attacks.